# file_get_contents does not work on port 8282

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I got the following basic script who make a basic POST request (I just want to make it work, after I'll add more stuff) :

```
#   Variables
$URL = 'http://******:8282/api/incoming_shipment/';

$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'contract_id'       => 'Showcare-R124276',
        'shipment_from'     => 'Montréal',
        'shipment_to'       => 'Chicago',
        'shipping_time'     => '2012-08-16 14:51:01',
        'tracking_cie'      => 'Poste Canada',
        'tracking_type'     => 'Standard',
        'tracking_number'   => 'EP645 9834 123 9773'
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($URL, FALSE, $context);

print_r($result);
```

The result give me :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://******:8282/api/incoming_shipment/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in D:\Inetpub\hightechhandling\api\api_push_contract.php on line 31

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\Inetpub\hightechhandling\api\api_push_contract.php on line 31
```

But When I go to the webpage with my browser, it work perfectly. I have tryed cURL and fsocketopen but that didn't work too. Any help please ? Thanks..

**EDIT** I added `set_time_limit (500);` and now the second error has disapear of course... but the first still remain.

Comment: why on port 8282? and is that the address responds to this port in your browser? if not, try one of Nmap ip address to see open ports

Comment: My webserver answer on 8282.. if I open the URL as http://****.com:8282/blabla yes, the webapge open in the browser. I don't understand nmap ip ?

Comment: As of the error message, the port is not the problem…

Comment: @feeela If I use 80, our regular website, it work...

Comment: If you're sure the port is open correctly, no need to use nmap. I do some test and I'll give back ;)

Comment: @atmon3r I did try again. Direct IP without port (so 80 as default). Working, I'm getting the content. I then got back to port 8282 and still, nothing happen, same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. Was sooo stupid. The problem is because the server that make the request (where the PHP file is), has a firewall enabled and the firewall allow only port 21, 22, 80, 3306 and 1433 for external request.

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS, using `file_get_contents()` to access URL on port other than 80 doesn't works with permission denied. It works only when selinux is set to "disabled" or "permissive".

Answer (score 0):

### From PHP Manual

> void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
>
> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
>   reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
>   seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
>   php.ini.
>
> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.
>   In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
>   seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is
>   made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.
>   If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

Comment: I understand, but as a POST request, it shouldn't take more then 30 seconds... I mean 1 second at max...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'header' => implode("\r\n", array("Connection: close", "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")),
```

(especially the connection: close bit)

Also: Can you duplicate the problem on the commanline with curl?

Comment: cURL give me `couldn't connect to host` but return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable selinux for security consideration, you can modify selinux policy for allow httpd to listen 8282

To list which ports allowed for httpd:
semanage port -l | grep -w http_port_t

To add port 8282:
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8282