# Unable to retrieve URL with file_get_contents

Tags: php, xml, file, file-get-contents, urlencode

Our monitoring software supports a stateless API that with the correct parameters returns either XML or JSON output to the browser. When trying to pull this information, I have found that file_get_contents, file, and any other approaches always fail with "failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

I have made sure that "allow_url_fopen" is enabled, tried the URL with and without encoding, using file_get_contents with and without stream context, and just to simplify it, tried pulling the URL contents for just the base URL without any parameters.

I am at a complete loss as to why nothing works to pull the contents from this URL. The URL works fine in the browser but seems inaccessible from PHP, even on different web-servers.

My full code...
<?php

```
$protocol = "http";
$prtg_url = "prtg.domain.net:8080/";
$prtg_user = "username";
$prtg_hash = "passhash";

function getSensorData($deviceid)
{
    $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'header'  => "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n",          
        'timeout' => 60
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $sensor_xml_url = $GLOBALS['protocol'] . "://". $GLOBALS['prtg_url'] .
                        "api/table.json?content=sensors&output=json&columns=objid,type,device,sensor,status&id=" .
                        $deviceid . "&username=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_user'] . "&passhash=" . $GLOBALS['prtg_hash'];

    $xml_url_encoded = rawurlencode($sensor_xml_url);

    if ($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($xml_url_encoded) == false)
    {
        echo "Error fetching XML\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $sensors = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);

        foreach ($sensors->item as $sensor)
        {
            $sensor_ping = $sensor->ping;
            $sensor_id = $sensor->objid;
            $sensor_type = $sensor->type;
            $sensor_typeraw = $sensor->type_raw;

            echo $sensor_ping . "</br>";
            echo $sensor_id . "</br>";
            echo $sensor_type . "</br>";
            echo $sensor_typeraw . "</br>";
        }
    }
}

getSensorData("3401");

?>
```

This also fails...

```
$results = file_get_contents(rawurlencode("http://prtg.domain.net:8080"));
echo $results;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you rawurlencoding that url? In doing so you're trying to get the contents from "http%3A%2F%2Fprtg.fragnet.net%3A8080"

Why not just: rawurlencode the actual parameters and leave the domain/subdomain/protocol/port alone etc.

$results = file_get_contents("http://prtg.fragnet.net:8080"); ?

Comment: I wasn't positive what needed to be raw encoded. As I mentioned though, I tried it both with/without encoding. Using the exact code you posted results in Warning: file_get_contents(http://prtg.fragnet.net:8080) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/fragnetn/public_html/dp/prtg.php on line 51

Comment: Is there any documentation on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, the API documentation is available at https://prtg.paessler.com/api.htm I posted on their support forums at http://kb.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/57903-prtg-api-is-inaccessible-from-php-script but they take ages to approve new questions/followups. While their response there was semi correct (my code actually does display results in browser), the entire problem is that I am unable to pull the contents of anything on that page with PHP.

Comment: Just to note, i've tried the exact same code (that you posted) on any other domain and it works absolutely fine, echoing back the exact HTML contents to me. It is just this particular "http://prtg.fragnet.net:8080" for some reason.

Comment: I stumbled across this thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059512/file-get-contents-does-not-work-on-port-8282 and it looks like this is some type of selinux issue or the firewall blocking port 8080 for external requests. I will go ahead and accept your answer since it is correct and this is just a stupid web-server configuration issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh. I should have thought of this. Sorry I didn't solve it for you :)

Comment: No problem! It looks like 8080 is open for TCP/UDP outgoing on my web-server. CURL/file_get_contents/fsockopen/etc. all continue to fail to that URL though so I can only assume SeLinux at this point!